# Ajax returned HTML is not rendering in PRE tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, pre

I have  a normal http get Ajax call that returns html pre formatted string: 
`'\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000a\u0009#07\/04\/2014#\u000a'`

I am trying to set this value in pre tag.

HTML: `<pre id="preContainer"></pre>`

JS: 
      `var container = document.getElementById('preContainer');`

Work if I pass it in code hardcode value:

```
container.innerHTML = '\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000a\u0009#07\/04\/2014#\u000a';
```

But do not work if I pass directly the ajax returned object (Angular JS GET Call):

```
httpFactory.getHTML(..id..).success(function (emailHTML, status) {

            var container = document.getElementById('preContainer');
            container.innerHTML = emailHTML;                
        });
```

Both the hardcode value and emailHTML value are exactly same. But in later it's not formatting in PRE tag. Any idea Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried jquery Get call and pre tag is rendering HTML fine. Somehow its not working with Angular JS http call.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they are not exactly the same, but what ever you're looking at to see the value (like chrome tools or w/e) is just showing it encoded or w/e.  (If they were exactly the same you'd have the same result)

Can you just encode the output again before putting into the innerHTML tag?

```
container.innerHtml = encodeHoweverYouEncode(emailHTML);
```

(That's probably not how you want it encoded, but use w/e encodes your value there)

Comment: Hi Kyle - When i am logging just after http call using console.log in chrome console window it's showing as a string but when i am copying and pasting again in console window its showing as formatted.